# How to run Android Things app automatically on boot?

Tags: android-things

When there is a power failure on my *Raspberry*, *Android Things* restarts on the main page without my application and I have to resend it manually, how can I fix *Android Things* to run the application automatically on reboot?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/things/training/first-device/create-studio-project#activity), you should include two `intent-filter`s for the app's launcher `Activity`, one for launching app deployed through *Android Studio* and another one for launching app on each boot:

```
<activity android:name=".HomeActivity">

    <!-- Launch activity as default from Android Studio -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>

    <!-- Launch activity automatically on boot, and re-launch if the app terminates. -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```